# Processes Not Appearing on Beowulf Cluster

Tags: python, linux, bash, multiprocessing, nohup

More than a week ago, I ran `nohup python3 -u script.py` on an Ubuntu beowulf cluster I was connected to via SSH. I've now gone back wanting to kill off these processes (this program is using multiprocesing with a Pool object), but I haven't been able to do so, as I haven't been able to find the PIDs. I know that the processes are still being run because `nohup.out` is still being appended to and other data is being generated, but nothing relevant seems to appear when I run commands like ps or top. For example, when I run `ps -x -U mkarrmann`, I get:

```
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1296920 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
1296929 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
1296937 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
1296939 ?        SNsl   0:00 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs
1296944 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
1296945 ?        R      0:00 sshd: mkarrmann@pts/0
1296960 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
1296965 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/3016/gvfs -f -o big_writes
1296972 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
1296979 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
1296980 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
1296987 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
1296992 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
1297001 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
1297005 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
1297014 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
1297126 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps -x -U mkarrmann
```

Or when I run `ps -faux | grep py`, I get:

```
root         975  0.0  0.0  34240  8424 ?        Ss   Jul28   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root        1046  0.0  0.3 476004 245516 ?       Ss   Jul28  66:45 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/glustereventsd --pid-file /var/run/glustereventsd.pid
root        1275  0.0  0.0  20612  7732 ?        S    Jul28   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/glustereventsd --pid-file /var/run/glustereventsd.pid
mkarrma+ 1297143  0.0  0.0   6380   736 pts/0    S+   14:40   0:00              \_ grep --color=auto py
```

Do any of these actually correspond to my Python processes and I'm just missing it? Anything else that I should try? I feel like the only thing I haven't tried is manually parsing through `/proc`, but that obviously shouldn't be necessary so I'm sure I'm missing something else.

I'm happy to provide any additional information that could be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be somehow due to the Beowulf cluster, if you are not seeing all the computers? I don't know anything about Beowulf so don't really know, just checked it in wikipedia a bit now.

Comment: @antont I don't believe so- my understanding and experience up to this point has been that it should function as a single server, but I included the fact that it was on Beowulf cluster since I don't know enough to be positive that it's irrelevant. I'll try look more into that, thanks.

Comment: Yes I also read that Beowulf should show it like a single machine. Otherwise my first thought was that it has crashed but you said you see new log entries and data coming in. I would triplecheck that it's actually the case.

Comment: @antont After logging in and out a bunch I finally got the processes to show up. Turns out it was due to a quirk of the beowulf system and I just had to be connected to correct node. Surprised I hadn't ran into this problem earlier, and this is obviously good to know going forward. Thanks for the help!